# How To Embed SWF In HTML?

Tags: flash

How To Embed SWF In HTML?

Answer (score 7):

The non-official industry standard is to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
 </script>
```

[Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation)

Comment: If you using .net and putting an swf into a master.page, use this:

 <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("<%=  this.ResolveUrl("~/live.swf") %>", "headerFlash", "924", "200", "9.0.0");
    </script>

Answer (score 3):

Use `SWFObject` as apphacker mentiond. Just in case you cannot use it (to support browsers with JS disabled), here is how to do it with HTML alone.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        id="myMovie" width="300" height="200"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
    <param name="movie" value="Movie.swf"/>
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <embed src="Movie.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"
        width="300" height="200" name="myMovie" align="middle" 
        play="true"
        loop="false"
        quality="high"
        allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashhtmlcode.php) what you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"

WIDTH="850"

HEIGHT="610"

CODEBASE="http://active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0">

<PARAM NAME="MOVIE" VALUE="2bigpinkballs2.swf">

<PARAM NAME="PLAY" VALUE="true">

<PARAM NAME="LOOP" VALUE="true">

<PARAM NAME="QUALITY" VALUE="high">

<PARAM NAME="SCALE" value="noborder">

<EMBED SRC="2bigpinkballs2.swf"    WIDTH="850"    HEIGHT="610" PLAY="true" LOOP="true"             QUALITY="high" 

scale="noborder"

PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"> </EMBED></OBJECT>
```