# What is the best way to embed a SWF file into a web page without using JavaScript?

Tags: flash

As the site will be totally in flash, there is no use of JavaScript required. So, what is the best way to embed a SWF file into a web page without using JavaScript. And why do you consider it to be the best one?

Comment: If you are not using js, is there any other way that using the good old object and embed tags? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053225/how-to-embed-swf-in-html/2054373#2054373

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Satay Method](http://www.puidokas.com/how-to-properly-embed-flash/):

```
 <!--[if IE]>
<object
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="movie.swf"
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0"
    width="200"
    height="400">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
</object><![endif]--><!--[if !IE]><!-->
<object
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="movie.swf"
    width="200"
    height="400">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
</object><!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example here: http://knowhow.dgx.cz/embedding-flash/
Contains hacks for crappy IE.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the [embedding code used by SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#How_to_embed_Flash_Player_content_using_SWFObject_static_publish) is tested to be working on as many browsers as possible. Just skip the steps with javascript.