# Putting a link to a flash object swf in a asp.net MasterPage

Tags: master-pages, flash

I have a asp.net master page that gets used by pages many /levels/deep/

I will put a link to a flash file in this template.

I tried doing it like this but it did not work, what the best practice here?

```
<object width="924" height="200">
<param name="movie" value="/live.swf">
<embed src="/live.swf" width="924" height="200">
</object>
```

Comment: You're missing `classid` and `codebase` for the `object` tag, without which IE might complain. Check this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053225/how-to-embed-swf-in-html/2054373#2054373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using .net and putting an swf into a master.page, use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
swfobject.embedSWF("<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/live.swf") %>", "headerFlash", "924", "200", "9.0.0"); 
</script>
```